# Validating and handling transaction proposal requests in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

The transaction flow in the Fabric states that:

1. Client proposes a transaction
2. This proposal is passed to all the endorsing peers of the network
3. Endorsing peer simulates the chaincode, signs the proposal and sends it back to the client.
4. The client collects the signature and waits until the total number of signature matches the one specified in the endorsement policy
5. Once the client has enough signatures, it sends this request to the Orderer
6. Orderer creates blocks and sends it to the anchor peers who validates and commits into their ledger

If we are using the Composer REST server, how are all these steps handled? Are they abstracted out from the client? Or do we need to explicitly write logic in the TP function or client to handle the proposal responses?

My confusion comes from the fact that when we use the node SDK, we have to explicitly implement the logic for handling all this. As we do it over [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/app/invoke-transaction.js#L52).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer implements a Submit/Notify model and that includes the Rest Server. It will submit the proposal, collect the endorsements, send them to the orderer and wait for a block with the transaction in to be committed before informing the caller of the completion of the transaction.

As Composer has no visibility of the endorsement policy it will send proposals to all peers in the channel (that have been defined as having the endorsingPeer role in the connection profile, which if not specified defaults to true) and collect as many responses as possible before sending them to be ordered. The Peer(s) will then decide whether those endorsements satisfy the endorsement policy.

Composer also waits for all peers (that have been defined in the connection profile as having the eventSource role which defaults to true if not specified) to notify that the transaction has been committed before notifying the client